# How to remove blank spaces from buffer

Tags: c, algorithm, buffer

> How to remove blank spaces from buffer in O(1) space complexity and
>   O(n) time complexity?

What do we mean by buffer in this question? will we consider it as a stream of characters or string? This was a question asked in a programming test

Comment: I would assume that they mean an array of some length (maybe a null terminated string).

Comment: Is `what do we mean` your question or part of the test?

Comment: Blank space? Is there a thing called non-blank space?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a (writable) string or a fixed array, which can be processed in place in O(n);

```
char* str = strdup("the big dog is cool"), *src = str, *dst = str;

while(*src) {
  if(*src != ' ')
    *dst++ = *src;
  src++;
}
*dst = 0;

// str is thebigdogiscool
```

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure if i am able to get your question correctly but if i am not wrong proceed in following way

Consider blank spaces ib buffer as 0s and non blank spaces as 1s 
Now you have character sequence or string or array of 0s and 1s 
Apply any sorting algorithm to sort these blank and non blank characters

Not sure am i making sense but surely its an option. Choice of sorting algo is yours